# How to ssh with username AND password linux automatically from bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Im trying to ssh with the Username AND password provided.

Restrictions: 
1. I DO NOT want to have to set up a public key for each of the servers I am trying to ssh into. 
2. I DO NOT want to/have access to install the sshpass tool.

Attempts:

```
echo examplePassword | ssh exampleUser@exampleServer
ssh exampleUser@exampleServer < password.txt (contains password)
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I had this problem my solution ended up being to use a public key. The reason ssh doesn't have this functionality is (probably) because it is a security issue.

Comment: Public keys are really the way to go.  It might seem "hard" at first, but once properly setup, it's by far the easiest, most powerful, and most secure solution.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19483365/611007 pointing out `$SSH_ASKPASS` described at http://www.debian-administration.org/article/587/pam_mount_and_sshfs_with_password_authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google search led me to this stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash

Though i have not used it before or tried it, it definitely looks reasonable assuming you have expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

Comment: Thanks, was hoping i could get away with not having to install any non built in functions but this seems to do the trick.

Comment: While this does work, it's an awful idea to store your password in plain-text in a text file. This exact situation is why `ssh` has the option for public key encryption. For anyone who finds this answer in future, I would strongly recommend learning how to setup a public key instead of opening up this massive security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $host = 'remote.serv.er';
my $user = 'root';
my $pass = 'hunter2';
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new('$host');
$ssh->login('$user', '$pass') or die "Oh noes! $!";
```

I have not tested this code, it was taken from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/241605/145134).

Comment: He said he doesn't want/have access to install sshpass

Comment: @u8sand - What the author wants is unrealistic.

Comment: @u8sand Oops. Updated with alternative.

Comment: A reasonable solution indeed. Hopefully he has both perl and perl's ssh library.